# Array move absolute diff - Python Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, diff

I need a method that takes array of floats that replaces items by the threshold
.
I have an array **test_input** and desired **test_output**
with the threshold = absolute{0.03}
so for each next number in the array if its bigger then 0.03 or smaller then 0.03 from the previose number , then more forward with this value.
inputs, outputs of the method:

```
 test_input  test_output
   0.842125     0.854551
   0.861899     0.854551
   0.844275     0.854551
   0.834159     0.854551
   0.841241     0.854551
   0.840570     0.854551
   0.842385     0.854551
   0.868493     0.854551
   0.865714     0.854551
   0.854551     0.854551
   0.839382     0.810607
   0.823355     0.810607
   0.840304     0.810607
   0.831483     0.810607
   0.828795     0.810607
   0.827270     0.810607
   0.810607     0.810607
   0.845127     0.843676
   0.849857     0.843676
   0.843676     0.843676
   0.923508     0.923508
   0.864685     0.871483
   0.844454     0.871483
   0.871483     0.871483
   0.937505     0.912550
   0.912550     0.912550
   0.842662     0.842662
   0.951625     0.951625
   0.901127     0.910291
   0.910291     0.910291
```

the method that generates **test_output** is not efficient:

```
import math 


def get_column_special_values(df, column='test_input', indexes=None, column_threshold=0.03):
        """
            the method gets the absolute value compare to the last min/max result 
            based on the column_threshold
        :param column: str of column name in the dataframe 
        :param df: DataFrame
        :param indexes: list
        :param column_threshold: float
        :return: list[float...]
        """
        column_special_values = []
        indexes = range(df.shape[0]) if indexes is None else indexes
        for row_index in indexes:
            current_column_value = df[column].iloc[row_index]
            if row_index == 0:
                column_special_values.append(current_column_value)
                continue
    
            last_column_value = column_special_values[row_index - 1]
            value_column_diff = math.fabs(
                last_column_value - current_column_value)
            if value_column_diff < column_threshold:
                value_column = last_column_value
            else:
                value_column = current_column_value
    
            column_special_values.append(value_column)
        return column_special_values
```

it is very inefficient for a lot of columns

method explanation:

1. iterate the input array
2. get the absolute diff from the last element chosen (first element is
   is selected if no previous elements) if the diff is bigger then the
   threshold then mark this element as a chosen element. else fill the
   last chosen element.

psuedo code:

```
If abs( Yn-1 - Xn)>Thr
        Yn=Xn
    Else
        Yn=Yn-1
```

I tried looking in pandas documentation and found [df.cummin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html) [df.cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) , [df.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), [df.abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html)
API methods but was troubling to construct a proper method.

Is there any efficient way to achieve proper results without for-loop?
in any way thank you very much for the help !

Comment: Can you explain the logic? What your function is doing?

Comment: re-edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you are trying to compare consequent values in the input column of a DataFrame to a threshold and then create a new column based on the results of that comparison. I believe you could use [df.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Based on the diff you calculate the cummax and cummin by the absolute of the value if the diff bigger then the threshold so . So for the solution diff is not enough

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do, the logic and how you got your output from running your function. Try experimenting with df.shift, df.diff and np.where.